# OOM IBM MQ 8.0.0.14

Tags: linux, ibm

Имеется IBM MQ 8.0.0.14 , Patch 14. Периодически приходит OOM killer убивает процесс amqzlaa0.

Вопрос  с чем это связано?
в системе 20+ гигов оперативки
IBM MQ запущен как systemd unit, пробовали обновляться, в итоге пришли к 14 патчу - результат тот же.
Система Debian like: Astra Linux  2.12.4 (Orel)

Кроме как периодического ребута решения не нашли.

*Update* Дополнил выводом OOM:
Вывод OOM:

```
[Ср янв 11 15:49:58 2023] Out of memory: Kill process 1636 (amqzlaa0) score 166 or sacrifice child
[Ср янв 11 15:49:58 2023] Killed process 1636 (amqzlaa0) total-vm:6591180kB, anon-rss:2174484kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:2263344kB
```

Comment: Логичный вопрос — что пишет OOM killer в момент убийства?

Comment: вот логи dmes -T 
`[Ср янв 11 15:49:58 2023] Out of memory: Kill process 1636 (amqzlaa0) score 166 or sacrifice child
[Ср янв 11 15:49:58 2023] Killed process 1636 (amqzlaa0) total-vm:6591180kB, anon-rss:2174484kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:2263344kB
`

Comment: Теоретически может оказаться, что память кушает кто-то другой, а OOM Killer запутывается и убивает невинный процесс. У вас настроен какой-нибудь мониторинг? Помониторьте, что происходит с сервером перед срабатыванием OOM Killer'а

Comment: дело втом что именно IBM MQ съедает все.
на сервере запущен только mq_exporter, node_exporter. То есть лишнего там нету. Ну и по мониторингу видно что после перезапуска идет плавное увеличение занимаемой  памяти, на лицо утечка, но как ее победить ..

Comment: Что-то у меня в голове картина не складывается, `anon-rss:2174484kB` это сильно меньше чем заявленные вами "20+ гигов оперативки"